# Taking the dot product of two arrays in python without for loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I have two arrays `W` and `x`. `W` has the shape `(16, 10)` and `x` has the shape `(10000, 16)`. I need to take the dot product between the transpose of `W` and `x`. The problem is that the shapes of `x` and `W` are very different so I keep getting an error when trying to do this. Of course I can do this with `for` loops but I want to do it without using any `for` loops.

```
for i in range(x.shape[0])
    s = (np.dot(W.transpose(), x[i])) + b
```

The above code produces an array, `s`, which consists of 10 entries. I'm trying to get `s` to be 10,000 lines with 10 entries in each line (without using a `for` loop).

Comment: since W.shape is (16,10) and x.shape is (10000,16). the dot product can be done between np.dot(x , W). the output shape will be (10000,10)

Comment: So you're saying I don't need to use the transpose for W?

Comment: Yes. based on your output requirement, it looks like that is the operation you are looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for

```
s = x.dot(W)
```

Or

```
s = x @ W
```

`dot` behaves as a for product for simple 1D vectors, but is full blown matrix multiplication otherwise. Since you want a `(10000, 10)` result shape, you need to set up your matrices to have that shape in the outer dimensions, and match the inner ones:

```
(10000, 16) x (16, 10) -> (10000, 10)
```

To perform the sum in whatever order you want, you can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
s= np.einsum('ik,ji->jk', W, x)
```

Or simply

```
s = np.einsum('ik,ji', W, x)
```